# Session Handling (PHP vs. JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

I am currently working on a little webshop and I need a good session handling for the shopping cart.
I worked with PHP and I never used JavaScript, but what is the diffrence when working with session handling? What is the simplest possibility?
Do I have to use cookies?

Does anybody know a good tutorial?

Comment: http://www.php.net is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the diffrence when working with session handling?

PHP has session handling functions built into the language. JavaScript doesn't (although there are [modules which add the functionality](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=sessions&q=site%3anpmjs.org&hl=en) and writing your own is not particularly difficult.

Of course, that assumes server side JavaScript. There are client side options which can have similar effects to sessions, but sessions are fundamentally a server side technique.

> What is the simplest possibility?

Cookies are the simplest way to track a session id.

> Do I have to use cookies?

No. You can pass session ids through query strings and hidden input fields.

Comment: Passing the session ids in the query string is the most insecure thing to do and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Ok, that's a good point to start with :)